# Bundle id is not showing in iTunesconnect Bundle ID

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

I am facing a strange issue that I have never faced before. I created a new appID with new Bundle ID, but it is not showing up in itunesconnect "Bundle ID".
I googled it and i found some questions regarding this, but only questions there are no answers on it.
 is there any way to tackling this issue,
 any help much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for me i sorted it out by emailing to Apple about the issue, then i got solution for that.

**Edit**
At that time when i had that issue, nothing did work for me i tried reload, refresh, sign out, restart system, nothing worked out.
I left with no option but to email to Apple on their support email, they fixed that manually for me. now it could be possible with reload page or sign out and sign in i am not sure.
 
Well there is nothing specific in email to apple on there technical support, just mention you are facing that problem, they might set this up manually for you. hope you got it.

Comment: Would be great if you told us the solution or how you emailed apple :\

Comment: I also called Apple Support, they're working on the issue for me too...

Answer (score 41):

Try to sign out, and then sign in to itunesconnect site. it worked for me

Comment: If that doesn't work, clear all website data in Safari and try again.

Comment: Amazing, just encountered this issue. Logging out and back in fixed it. This question was asked SIX YEARS ago! And it still hasn't been fixed...

Comment: This didnt even work for me! Even a NEW browser, and new computer.

Answer (score 24):

I just had to create an App Id and then log out of iTunes connect and back in again.
iTunes connect is truly awful.

Comment: t r u l y    a w f u l

Comment: For me logging out did the trick... clicking on "+" -> 'New App' redirected me to the home page.. nothign else... wtf...

Comment: This didnt even work for me! Even a NEW browser.

Answer (score 8):

I've seen this happen myself from time to time, but so far it's always been down to a delay in iTunes Connect and has sorted itself out without me doing anything other than waiting!

Comment: for me i sorted it out by emailing to Apple about the issue, then i got solution for that. Thanks for reply

Comment: @umersufyan share the solution man.Or the mailing is the solution

Comment: @BlackMamba Well there is nothing specific in Email to apple on there technical support, just mention you are facing that problem, they might set this up manually for you. hope you got it.

Answer (score 6):

Like this guy [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/bundle-id-not-showing-up-in-drop-down-on-itunes-connect.197133/), the solution for me was wait, so apple could process my new id. (about 6 hours or so).

Comment: Same solution for me, although it was more like 6 minutes for me.

Comment: 6 hours? lmao how efficient of the world's largest company

Comment: I didn't track the exact amount of time, I left work and in when I arrived the other day it was ok.

Answer (score 6):

For me it was to check the **removed apps** list — someone has already used that Bundle ID and removed the app associated with it before.

[image]

Comment: So, what have you done? Have you restored the app ? or You've just created new identifiers?

Answer (score 4):

Login to member centre and create a distribution profile using the same app id which you are going to use in the iTunes Connect. Then logout from iTunes Connect and Login again and try. It will show the Bundle ID in the drop down menu.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 4):

If you tried to create the app record and if the app or bundle id does not appear:

In order for you to be able to see the app record in iTunes Connect, the team agent of the account must login and adjust your settings so that you are able to view the app.

Please provide the team agent with the following steps to add your access to the app.

1. In the Users and Roles pane, select the user you want to edit by clicking on their Apple ID.
2. Select the Roles pane.
3. In the Apps window, the team agent can add the newly created app to the users access, by selecting the down arrow in the window, and choosing the new app.
4. Once the new app is added, click Save.

Once this information has been updated by the team agent, you will be able to view the app in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 2):

Refreshing and sign out/signing in again doesn't worked.
In my case what worked is to contact apple support team for the concern, they added it manually and it was there after waiting for 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that we had previously deleted/archived the apps with such bundle identifiers. But this was long long time ago, I didn't even remember that. So they just had to be recovered in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 1):

https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/

Have you ever heard '**XC Wildcard-**' option to create new iOS or tvOS app creating new bundle ID on AppStoreConnect platform? Yes it is possible with '**XC Wildcard-**' option. So if your bundle ID does not appear on the AppStoreConnect;

- Click **+ (Plus button)** and Select the **New App** option.
- Enter needed informations and choose '**XC Wildcard-***' option from **Bundle ID** section.
- After that, you'll see **Bundle ID Suffix** text box. Enter your bundle identifier there and
- Click the **Create button**.

If your bundle id is not using from other apps, your app will generated successfully. Otherwise, you can change your bundle id and you can create your app on AppStoreConnect.

Comment: I tried this but it just says there was a problem and try again later. This never changes.

Comment: @DrorBar are you sure to use unique bundle identifier?

Comment: Yes. I sent a message to support and the next day it resolved itself.

Answer (score 0):

for me the solution was to resister a new id, then  choose this id and save, then logout again and login and now you can see your bundle id.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of this issue, I create separate profiles for my extensions and app targets as well that are definitely paired with single app id. I had SiriKit extensions in my app and multiple targets along.

Answer (score 0):

These Steps Worked for me.

- Logout from itunes connect
- Login to apple developer account
- Delete existing identifier
- Create new identifier with Explicit radio box checked next to BundleID [image: See Attached Image]
- Login to Itunes connect again
- Hopefully you'll be able to see bundle identifier there.

Answer (score 0):

In My case, I've Just removed an App From AppStore Connect(Not yet released into AppStore). But I can see that  THE APP IS NOT COMPLETELY REMOVED, but categorized under "Removed Apps". Now I want to create a new app in Appstore connect using the same bundle ID that I've used in the app that I just removed, But my BundleID is invisible while creating new App. I've just Mailed Apple regarding this. Will keep you posted on this.

Answer (score -1):

I've had this same issue a few times, and it's been for different reasons.  Here's a few things to check:

1) Did you set the developer profile in xCode?  When you create a new project it sets the developer ID, so if you're trying to make a new one to.. lets say... do an ad-hoc release, it won't be present in the old project.  It's set in targets>build settings>code signing

2) Download your profiles from the organizer. New profiles need to be loaded into xCode

3) Close/quit and reopen xCode, sometimes it breaks.

4) Try doing a clean

Comment: Well Thanks for response, i appreciate it , that is an itunesconnect when you upload new app to it with new BundleID, it is not showing up in itunesconnect, still it is disappeared for some reason that i don't know, perhaps Apple is manually updating their server

Answer (score -1):

It seems that in Xcode 13, for new apps the app's Name, Bundle ID, etc... is set within Xcode during the upload process.